# PowerModels and JuMP version conflict: Unsatisfiable requirements

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia. I wanted to test out some basic function calls in the `PowerModels` package with Julia 1.1.0 (it passed the `Pkg.test()`) so I wrote a few lines according to their tutorial:

```
using PowerModels
using Ipopt
using JuMP  # example didn't have this line

run_ac_opf("case5.m", JuMP.with_optimizer(Ipopt.Optimizer))
```

I saved it as `test1.jl`, ran it on REPL with `include("test1.jl")` and got the following error:

```
julia> include("test1.jl")
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: with_optimizer not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] include at .\boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [3] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [4] include(::String) at .\client.jl:403
 [5] top-level scope at none:0
```

I'm not sure what's the cause for this error since when I tried both deleting the `using JuMP` and changing to `using JuMP.with_optimizer`, I still get the `UndefVarError`.

**UPDATE**
I tried `] rm JuMP` and `] rm PowerModels`, and added the latest v0.19.1 JuMP (I tried only removing my v0.18.5 JuMP but it conflicted with my installed PowerModels package. However, now when I try `] add PowerModels`, it gives me the following error:

```
(v1.1) pkg> add PowerModels
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package JuMP [4076af6c]:
 JuMP [4076af6c] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.19.1 or uninstalled
 ├─JuMP [4076af6c] is fixed to version 0.19.1
 └─found to have no compatible versions left with PowerModels [c36e90e8] 
   └─PowerModels [c36e90e8] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.1.0, 0.2.0-0.2.3, 0.3.0-0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.5.0-0.5.1, 0.6.0-0.6.1, 0.7.0-0.7.2, 0.8.0-0.8.8, 0.9.0-0.9.6] or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.1.0, 0.2.0-0.2.3, 0.3.0-0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.5.0-0.5.1, 0.6.0-0.6.1, 0.7.0-0.7.2, 0.8.0-0.8.8, 0.9.0-0.9.6]
```

This is what `] status` gives me:

```
(v1.1) pkg> status
    Status `C:\Users\me\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.1.0.1\environments\v1.1\Project.toml`
  [c52e3926] Atom v0.8.5
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.18.1
  [916415d5] Images v0.18.0
  [4076af6c] JuMP v0.19.1 [`C:\Users\me\.julia\dev\JuMP`]
  [e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.7.0
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v0.24.0
  [438e738f] PyCall v1.91.2
  [d330b81b] PyPlot v2.8.1+ [`C:\Users\me\.julia\dev\PyPlot`]
```

Seems like I can only use v0.9.6 PowerModels, but according to its github page the stable release is now v0.10.0. Any suggestions?

**SOLVED**
JuliaPro was the problem. I installed the standalone Julia and was able to use both JuMP and PowerModels.

Comment: What does `import Pkg; Pkg.status("JuMP")` print out?

Comment: @MattB. It says I have v0.18.5 installed. I read somewhere that `with_optimizer` is available in v0.19 or later, so I tried `] rm JuMP` and `] add JuMP`, but it's still adding the 0.18.5 JuMP.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  The packages available in JuliaPro intentionally lag behind a bit to keep things a bit more stable — but unfortunately it means that you don't have access to the latest and greatest.

Comment: @MattB. So... there is no way around it?

Comment: There are several ways around. One is manually adding packages like you've done, but then you also need to manually add upgraded dependencies as required.  Another is to completely switch JuliaPro to the general registry (but then you can't go back).

Comment: I tried `] add PowerModels@0.9.6` and still got an error similar to before: `restricted to versions 0.9.6 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.9.6`. I'll try looking into the general registry option.